# Pull from develop branch to feature branch in Smartgit

Tags: git, smartgit

I am working in a team. I am working in a feature branch. But in the mean time, my another mate finished a feature which is in develop branch. For my project I need the changes from develop branch. What to do? I am trying to pull. But it shows me like that. It doesn't show me which branch I want to pull from. So what to do pull from develop branch to my branch?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeIwm.png)

Answer (score 0):

*Pulling* means fetching and merging/rebasing to the *tracked* branch. Usually, you will not have your feature branch tracking `develop`, hence you need a little bit of extra work:

If you are using *Git-Flow* and you are actually in a *feature* branch (your current branch will show up in **Features** category in the **Branches** view), then invoke **Branch|Git-Flow|Integrate Develop**.

if you are not using *Git-Flow*, just use **Branch|Rebase** or **Branch|Merge** and be sure to select the *remote* `develop` there (usually this will be `origin/develop`).